# How to isolate the war classloading in wildfly 10. Getting a visibility issue for org.apache.cxf.enpoint.Client class

Tags: jax-ws, classloader, soap-client, wildfly-10, class-visibility

I am trying to deploy a war which has a JAX-WS client for SOAP services in Wildfly 10.1.0.Final. When I am trying to get the port for the webservice the delegate interface in javax.xml.ws.Service automatically going to apache cxf implementation of getPort() method.

When its internally try to create a proxy connection, I am getting a IllegalArgumentException as org.apache.cxf.enpoint.Client is not visible to classloader.

I have read the documentation and the classloading hierarchy of wildfly. Wildfly has a cxf-core.jar(3.1.6) and my war also have cxf-core.jar(3.1.7). My estimation is that it is trying to access the cxf-core.jar from wildfly and throwing classloading issue.

JBOSS has different meta files for altering the flow of normal class loading like jboss-web.xml, jboss-classloading.xml etc. My query which meta file should I use to resolve this visibility issue of classloader.

What will be the meta file, what is the content and what are the references that I need to write in contents(say war name mywar.war).

Error trace that I am getting :

> 13:38:22,877 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d) Creating Service {http://exp.com/webservices/}CustomerRelationshipManagementWebService from WSDL: http://localhost:5321/Nsb.CustomerRelationshipManagement.WebService.asmx?wsdl
>   13:39:18,632 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client is not visible from class loader
>   13:39:18,642 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:581)
>   13:39:18,646 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:557)
>   13:39:18,648 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(WeakCache.java:230)
>   13:39:18,654 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:127)
>   13:39:18,656 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:419)
>   13:39:18,662 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:719)
>   13:39:18,664 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ProxyHelper.getProxyInternal(ProxyHelper.java:47)
>   13:39:18,666 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ProxyHelper.getProxy(ProxyHelper.java:101)
>   13:39:18,669 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:175)
>   13:39:18,671 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)
>   13:39:18,673 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:493)
>   13:39:18,675 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl$JBossWSServiceImpl.createPort(ProviderImpl.java:578)
>   13:39:18,680 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:359)
>   13:39:18,691 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:350)
>   13:39:18,700 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:99)
>   13:39:18,705 ERROR [stderr] (e99c3221-b10d-4fe7-b0ff-22fac3e1754d)      at com.abc.client.CustomerRelationshipManagementWebService.getCustomerRelationshipManagementWebServiceSoap(CustomerRelationshipManagementWebService.java:72)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me know if the answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the JBoss web service subsystem from your deployment by adding a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file to the WAR's WEB-INF folder.

**Source:**  [Exclude a Subsystem from a Deployment](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/html/development_guide/exclude_a_subsystem_from_a_deployment)

Here is a an example which would do it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">  
      <deployment>  
        <exclude-subsystems>   
          <subsystem name="webservices" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <dependencies>
          <module name="org.apache.cxf" />
          <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl" />
        </dependencies>  
      </deployment>  
    </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: I have tried that after doing it the war itself is not deploying.

Comment: And you bundled cxf-core.jar(3.1.7) in your WAR lib or EAR lib folder?  Can you add an "Update" (edit) your question and add the relevant log traces?

Comment: I am not using any EAR and the cxf-core.jar(3.1.7) is in my WAR/WEB-INF/lib. I have added the error stack trace I am getting while try to call the soap service.